# LinkedIn Follow Button Requires External Login on Website

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

What is the precise behavior that should be expected of the Follow Company button (https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company) provided by LinkedIn?

If a user is already logged into LinkedIn, nothing appears to happen when the user clicks the **FOLLOW** button. Clicking the button WILL
cause them to follow that company, but the user must manually navigate to the company's LinkedIn page to confirm this.

If the user is NOT logged in to LinkedIn, clicking the FOLLOW button prompts a login in a popup window, but submitting credentials does NOT change the users FOLLOW status with the company, nor does it take the user to the company's LinkedIn page. Other than logging the user in, there is no effect.

Is this behavior what's to be expected of the LinkedIn FOLLOW button? Has anyone managed to have the button require login and then have it follow the company in one process?